# Технология клиент-сервер (Веб-браузер и веб-сервер)

Tags: веб-сервер, пакет, tcp-ip, клиент-сервер, ip

Здравствуйте!
При балансировки траффика на сервера пользуясь методом трансляции сетевых адресов (Network Address Translation, NAT) балансировщик заменяет в полученном пакете от клиента ip-адрес отправителя(на свой VIP-адрес) и назначения(на IP веб-сервера). Потом сервер обработает запрос и собственно вопрос какие операции будут проводиться с ip-адресами чтобы доставить пакет клиенту?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Никаких. В ответе сервера в качестве адреса назначения будет указан клиентский IP.

Comment: а откуда сервер знает клиентский ip? Его же заменил балансировщик на свой vip-адрес

Comment: Балансировщик заменяет IP сервера (адрес назначения) на адрес сервера. Исходный адрес остаётся прежним.

Comment: но сервер находится же в локальной сети и он не как не может же знать ip-адрес клиента, то есть когда сервер начнет отправлять пакет он не поймет кому отправлять(он знает ip-адреса компьютеров локальной сети и vip-адрес балансировщика). Я как понимаю vip-адрес балансировщика - это внутренний ip-адрес для обмена внутри локальной сети.

Comment: Для серверов во внутренней сети внутренний адрес балансировщика является шлюзом по умолчанию. Отправлять он будет всё-же на адрес клиента, а поскольку он (клиент) не принадлежит локальной внутренней сети, то пакет уйдёт через шлюз.

Comment: Просто прочитал несколько статей в интернете и везде написано что балансировщик при методе NAT преобразует сначала ip-адреса перед отправлением на сервер и потом после получение от сервера, и только потом отправит клиенту.

Comment: Вот, нашёл картинку:

![Балансировка](http://alohalb.files.wordpress.com/2011/07/layer4_nat_data_flow.png?w=640&h=188)

Красно-синяя коробочка это балансировщик.

Comment: спасибо большое теперь все понятно.

Answer (score 0):

У всех клиентов подсети внешний адрес соответствует адресу шлюза.
Настраивал на своём PC шлюз подобным образом (wi-fi)
http://www.iz-news.ru/images/pics/lect/nat.gif